# Python: what's wrong with my nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

Using the while loop, I wrote a procedure that takes as input a positive whole number, and prints out a multiplication table showing all the whole number multiplications up to and including the input number. The order in which the equations are printed matters.

for example, print_multiplication_table(2) gives:
1 * 1  
1 * 2  
2 * 1  
2 * 2

**This is my code:**

```
def print_multiplication_table(n):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    while a <= n:
        while b <= n:
            print str(a) + " * " + str(b)
            b = b + 1
        a = a + 1
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as it only print out

```
1 * 1
1 * 2
```

Does anyone know why? thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `while` rather than a `for` which would seem more appropriate here. Also, your indentation is still a bit off - the body of the function should be indented.

Comment: Please consider going back to some of the questions you have written in the past and marking any answer that helped you in solving problems as the "answer".

Comment: I would love to mark them but I don't see anywhere I can mark it.. I'm too noob tell me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize counter for inner loop before its execution

```
def print_multiplication_table(n):
    a = 1
    b = 1 # won't do harm, but doesn't really need now
    while a <= n:
        b = 1 # <-- note
        while b <= n:
            print str(a) + " * " + str(b)
            b = b + 1
        a = a + 1
```

Comment: but, in my code, even though I didn't initialize b inside of loop, it still prints out 1 * 1 and 1 * 2 .... and the only thing that didn't work was the value a, which is already initilized... can anyone explain me why?

Comment: The first iteration of the _outer_ loop work correctly: the _inner_ loop is executed. But the second iteration of the _outer_ loop doesn't reinitialize `b` which is equals to `n + 1` after inner loop execution. So the inner loop isn't executed(because guard condition `b <= n` is false)

Comment: Oooops. :) Fixed now. Thanks. Well, I do most of my programming in C++ and I use python occasionally. Although I usually check my code before submission, this time I added comments after posting it, so neither syntax highlighter nor python interpreter complained

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `for` in place of `while`:

```
def print_multiplication_table(n):
    for a in range(1, n+1):
        for b in range(1, n+1):
            print str(a) + " * " + str(b)
```

which gives:

```
1 * 1
1 * 2
2 * 1
2 * 2
```

Using `for` will automatically keep track of your counter variables and avoid the type of error you encountered (this of course doesn't mean you can't make errors with `for`-loops, but it's easier to avoid the type of error you had)

Answer (score 3):

Easier still with a Python comprehension:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{} * {}'.format(a,b) for a in range(1,6) for b in range(1,6))
1 * 1
1 * 2
1 * 3
1 * 4
1 * 5
2 * 1
# etc...
```

Or, if you want the terminal new line:

```
>>> gen=('{} * {}'.format(a,b) for a in range(1,6) for b in range(1,6))
>>> print '\n'.join(gen),'\n'
```

I used a separate gen expression just to more clear about the print with the comma. This also works:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{} * {}'.format(a,b) for a in range(1,6) for b in range(1,6)),'\n'
```

There is no reason to do an explicit call to `str` in your code. If you don't, you can still use a and b as integers:

```
>>> gen=('{} * {} = {:2}'.format(a,b,a*b) for a in range(1,3) for b in range(1,4))
>>> print '\n'.join(gen),'\n'
1 * 1 =  1
1 * 2 =  2
1 * 3 =  3
2 * 1 =  2
2 * 2 =  4
2 * 3 =  6
```

Comment: Could drop the brackets and use a genexp instead.  This also has one minor quirk: there's no terminal `\n`, although that probably doesn't matter much.